# Separating real and imaginary parts from a plane wave expansion

Tags: complex-numbers, special-functions, bessel-functions

From a plane wave equation
$$e^{ix \cos{\varphi}}=\sum_{n=-\infty}^\infty J_{n}(x)[ie^{i\varphi}]^n$$
If I set $\varphi=0$, how can I separate them into real and imaginary parts?
I want to know how the answer can become
$$e^{ix}=\sum_{n=-\infty}^\infty i^n \space J_{n}(x)\tag1$$
and
$$\cos(x)=J_0(x)+2\sum_{n=1}^\infty (-1)^n J_{2n}(x)\tag2$$

Comment: (1) is just your initial plane wave expansion evaluated at $\varphi=0$. For (2), you'll need to know how $J_{-n}(x)$ relates to $J_{n}(x)$.

Comment: Try using the Bessel function generating function $e^{(\frac{x}{2})(\frac{t-1}{t})}$, substituting $t=e^{i\theta}$, taking the real part of the generating function, using Semiclassical's hint, and plugging in $\theta=\frac{\pi}{2}$.